# Method to find the most recently created custom objects?

Tags: custom-object

Is there a way via the platform to find the most recent items of a specific objects? I know you can do this via SOQL, but is there a way for platform users to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a tabular report on the object that includes the field "date created".  All custom objects have this field.  If you want to find the most recently modified version of the object, use the "date modified" field instead.

Once the report is created, click on the column header (eg. "date created") to sort the objects as you want.

Comment: This, or just create a list view under the Sobject (if it has a tab available) which can be sorted by created date or last modified date depending on what you are looking for